# Is there a way to change SwiftLint version in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, swiftlint

I'm attempting to use SwiftLint version 0.50.1 in my Azure DevOps pipeline to check iOS builds. Currently, the latest SwiftLint version is 0.53.0. However, I encountered some issues while trying to switch to version 0.50.1.

Here's what I tried:

I started by uninstalling the current SwiftLint version using the command 'brew uninstall swiftlint'.
Then, I attempted to install SwiftLint version 0.50.1 using 'brew install swiftlint@0.50.1'. However, I received an error message that mentioned 'No available formula with the name "swiftlint@0.49.1".'
I also attempted to use 'brew switch swiftlint x.xx.x' to switch to version 0.50.1, but I encountered another error: 'Error: Unknown command: switch.'

I would appreciate some assistance in resolving these issues.

I started by uninstalling the current SwiftLint version using the command 'brew uninstall swiftlint'.
Then, I attempted to install SwiftLint version 0.50.1 using 'brew install swiftlint@0.50.1'. However, I received an error message that mentioned 'No available formula with the name "swiftlint@0.49.1".'
I also attempted to use 'brew switch swiftlint x.xx.x' to switch to version 0.50.1, but I encountered

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope it will help resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi there, If the answer below could help address your concerns, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which may help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint), [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) is the recommended way to install a **specific version** of SwiftLint since it supports installing a pinned version rather than simply the **latest (which is the case with Homebrew)**.

Taking my demo for example, I added the `Podfile` for my `xcodeproj` with contents below.
[image]

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Github Xcode Demo' do
  pod 'SwiftLint', '0.50.1'
end
```

In the pipeline, I used `CocoaPods@0` task to install `SwiftLint@0.50.1`. Please pay attention to the path where the `SwiftLint` was downloaded.

```
steps:
- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'pod install'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 'Github Xcode Demo'

#SwiftLint@0.50.1 was retrieved under the path "$(build.Repository.LocalPath)/Github Xcode Demo/Pods/SwiftLint/"
- script: |
   "$(build.Repository.LocalPath)/Github Xcode Demo/Pods/SwiftLint/swiftlint" --version
  displayName: 'swiftlint version'
```

[image]

Hope the information would help.